# Dotfuscator post build for visual studio setup project VS 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, dotfuscator

I am using Visual Studio 2013. I have a .NET application that is getting deployed via Visual Studio Setup Project. Right now I have the Primary Output of the application begin used in the setup project. I want to use the Dotfuscator tool to obfuscate my code and then used the dotfuscated output for my setup project. Can someone lead me in the right direction?

I  have tried the following
1: On my application post-build event, pass my .xml configuration file from Dotfuscator to the Dotfuscator application. This created an obfuscated exe, but it was still deploying the regular exe with my setup project

1. On my application post-build event, pass my exe to the Dotfuscator command line tool with the community edition...it would create a obfuscated exe in the Dotfuscated folder and then copy it over to my Release folder. However, the setup project was still deploying the regular exe with my setup project.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer via another thread...I was not aware the Visual Studio Setup Project pulled the 'Primary Output' from the obj folder instead of the bin folder. I copied by obfuscated exe to the obj folder before the setup project was built and this worked.